# Help me i386 EFI Boot-up

Tags: boot, uefi, 32-bit

Do all flavours of Ubuntu support 32-bit UEFI?
I want to boot up 32-bit Ubuntu system using UEFI.
If I want to boot up 32-bit Ubuntu system, should I choose IA32 architecture?

Comment: What computer is it? - I can do it With Ubuntu in standard PCs with a persistent live drive made with *mkusb* with *usb-pack-efi* - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent

Comment: My computer is VMware Virtual PC.

Comment: I don't know if VMware can boot from USB, but you can try. In linux you can run KVM plus virt-manager, where the virtual machines can boot from USB (and mkusb creates a USB boot drive). You can try.

Comment: choose the 64-bit iso and cross your fingers the installer will figure out your exotic situation. It's worked for me several times ;) But these days I modify the iso with a script to make sure it installs the 32-bit bootloader for my 32-bit UEFI only machine

Answer (score 2):

Only 64 bit EFI is supported at present. To support this we (I am a member of the Ubuntu kernel team) need work in the installer, which is outside the remit of the kernel team, however, there are ramifications on the kernel side too to ensure this works correctly.

Also in consideration is the support for 32 bit x86 systems too, I'm not sure what the current policy of that is.  A [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1341944) has been filed, so it is on the radar for sure.

Comment: Was there originally 32-bit EFI supported?

Comment: EFI was originally a 64-bit only design, however, 32 bit EFI is being pushed by Intel, so it will (or is) happening.

Comment: This is incorrect, otherwise I would not be typing this from my 32-bit UEFI 64-bit 16.10 system (yeah, it is possible to have a 32-bit bootloader boot a 64-bit kernel...)

Comment: Could you pelase expand on this a little? If you're a member of the Ubuntu kernel team, as your profile mentions, could you give as a few gritty details? Is this new? Has it always been this way? Any workarounds? Zanna claims to have a 32bit EFI on a 64bit system.

Comment: Here is a bug report on that: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1341944 (shamelessly stolen from chat)

Comment: To support this we need work in the installer, which is outside the remit of the kernel team, however, there are ramifications on the kernel side too to ensure this works correctly.  Also in consideration is the support for 32 bit x86 systems too, I'm not sure what the current policy of that is.  A bug has been filed, so it is on the radar for sure.